# Select range with specific criteria to export into multiple CSV files

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to convert the attached Excel file into multiple CVS files in the following manner:

1. Column A = Column C values (Source Value) from Excel under a static Header title = Source Value
2. Column B = Column G values (Target Value) from Excel under a static Header title = Target Value
3. Naming convention of the CVS file = Column E (Controlling Picklist Field Name)_Column A (Display Name)_Column B (Field Name) --- e.g. Type_ClientType_PICK_004 --- please note that I have attached an example CVS file for what the output should look at

In addition to the above - I would like the VBA code to be a loop to find the UNIQUE values in Column E (Controlling Picklist Field Name) and separate the CVS files utilizing this column. For example, all rows under Column E criteria = 'Type', THEN create a new CVS file... all rows under criteria Column E = 'Industry', THEN create a new CVS file... etc.

If I could get the above VBA code and have all the CVS files be saved in a determined file path that would be AMAZING! Thanks so much.

Comment: There are contract programming sites for this type of thing. Stack Overflow isn't one of those.  If you'd like to make a stab at actually writing the code, people here will help, but we don't do your project for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ExportRangetoFile()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xFile As Variant
Dim xFileString As String

On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ActiveSheet.Copy
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
WorkRng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set xFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xFileString = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:="Comma Separated Text (*.CSV), *.CSV")
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileString, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```